# PHP XML Serialisation from object/array with indentation (replacement of pear/XML_serializer)

Tags: php, xml, xml-serialization, indentation

**pear/XML_Serializer** can take **indent** parameter which will be used as indentation character(to get human readable, well formatted XML)

I am trying to find a replacement for this package, but no one has similar feature.

Can someone advise a solution? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: XMLWriter has that AFAIK: http://php.net/xmlwriter-set-indent-string

Comment: Thanks found also Symfony/Serializer - nice stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony/Serializer can do that with **xml_format_output**

```
use \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
$serializer = new Serializer(array(), new XmlEncoder());
$array = array('your' => 'data');
echo $serializer->serialize($array, 'xml', array('xml_format_output' => true));
```